# Sinon spy.called no working

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, sinon

### Background

I have a small server that receives data from a machine. Every time I receive a message I call a function in a dispatcher object that simply `console.log`s everything it receives.

### Problem

The code works well as I can see the `console.log`s in the console, but Sinon `spy.called` doesn't work. It is always `false` no matter how many times I call `dispatcher.onMessage`.

### Code

**server.js**

```
const eventDispatcher = {
    onMessage: console.log,
};

const server = (dispatcher = eventDispatcher) => {


    //this gets called everytime the server receives a message
    const onData = data => {

        //Process data
        //....
        dispatcher.onMessage(data);
    };


    const getDispatcher = () => dispatcher;

    return Object.freeze({
        getDispatcher
    });
};
```

**test.js**

```
describe("message sender", () => {

    const myServer = serverFactory();


    it("should send information to server", () => {
        dummyMachine.socket.write("Hello World!\r\n");

        const dataSpy = sinon.spy(myServer.getDispatcher(), "onMessage");
        expect(dataSpy.called).to.be.true; //always fails!
    });

});
```

### Research

After reading similar posts I believe this happens due to some layer of indirection, as pointed in:

- [Sinon Spy is not called if the spied method is called indirectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041079/sinon-spy-is-not-called-if-the-spied-method-is-called-indirectly)

And should be fixed via using `this`:

- [Sinon.spy on a method is not invoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34795934/sinon-spy-on-a-method-is-not-invoked)

However, looking at my code I really can't get what I am missing.

### Question

- What am I doing wrong?

### MCVE

**Directory Structure**

```
 Project_Folder
 |____package.json
 |____server.js
 |____test
      |____ dummyMachine_spec.js
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "sinon-question",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "MCVE about a dummy machine connecting to a server for StackOverflow",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --reporter spec --slow 5000 --timeout 5000 test/*_spec.js || true"
  },
  "author": "Pedro Miguel P. S. Martins",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "sinon": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "net": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

**server.js**

```
"use strict";

const net = require("net");

const eventDispatcher = {
    onMessage: console.log,
};

const server = (dispatcher = eventDispatcher) => {

    let serverSocket;

    const onData = data => {
        //Process data
        dispatcher.onMessage(`I am server and I got ${data}`);
    };

    const start = (connectOpts) => {
        return new Promise(fulfil => {
            serverSocket = net.createConnection(connectOpts, () => {
                serverSocket.on("data", onData);   
                fulfil();
            });
        });
    };

    const stop = () => serverSocket.destroy();

    const getDispatcher = () => dispatcher;

    return Object.freeze({
        start,
        stop,
        getDispatcher
    });
};

module.exports = server;
```

**test/dummyMachine.js**

```
"use strict";


const chai = require("chai"),
    expect = chai.expect;

const sinon = require("sinon");
const net = require("net");
const serverFactory = require("../server.js");

describe("Dummy Machine", () => {

    const dummyMachine = {
        IP: "localhost",
        port: 4002,
        server: undefined,
        socket: undefined
    };

    const server = serverFactory();

    before("Sets up dummyReader and server", done => {

        dummyMachine.server = net.createServer(undefined, socket => {
            dummyMachine.socket = socket;
        });

        dummyMachine.server.listen(
            dummyMachine.port,
            dummyMachine.IP,
            undefined,
            () => {
                server.start({
                    host: "localhost",
                    port: 4002
                })
                .then(done);
            }
        );
    });

    after("Kills dummyReader and server", () => {
        server.stop();
        dummyMachine.server.close();
    });

    it("should connect to server", done => {
        dummyMachine.server.getConnections((err, count) => {
            expect(err).to.be.null;
            expect(count).to.eql(1);
            done();
        });

    });

    it("should send information to server", () => {
        dummyMachine.socket.write("Hello World\r\n");

        const dataSpy = sinon.spy(server.getDispatcher(), "onMessage");
        expect(dataSpy.called).to.be.true; //WORK DAAMN YOU!
    });
});
```

### Instructions for MCVE

1. Download the files and create the directory structure indicated.
2. Enter project folder and type `npm install` on a terminal
3. Type `npm test`

The first test should pass, meaning a connection is in fact being made.

The second test will fail, even though you get the console log, proving that `onMessage` was called.

Comment: Where would `onMessage` get called then? Between creating the spy and checking if it got called, I don't see any other code being run.

Comment: When the server receives data, it calls onMessage. The console.log shows, bit the spy doesn't work ...

Comment: You're creating the spy and _immediately_ checking if it got called. Node.js isn't multithreaded, so there's no context switching (i.e. time for the server to receive anything) between those two operations.

Comment: This confuses me. Are you telling me that if I do a `setTimeout` of 1 second and then try to call the spy, it will work?

Comment: It _might_, but the correct way of solving this is to implement an asynchronous test. However, the code you're posting here doesn't provide enough insight to determine how everything is connected in your app. What is `dummyMachine.socket.write()` doing, for instance? Consider creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I thought it was clear from the example and from the explanation how it was supposed to work. socket.write() sends data from the dummyMachine to the server. When the server receives the said data, it print it, but the spy isn't  notified. I will try to elaborate something more complete and post it here.

Comment: done, I added a MCVE that correctly illustrates the issue. It is a very small project, only 2 real files plus the `package.json`. Please feel free to have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that it's not enough to just spy on `onMessage`, because your test will never find out *when* it got called exactly (because stream events are asynchronously delivered).

You can use a hack using `setTimeout()`, and check and see if it got called some time after sending a message to the server, but that's not ideal.

Instead, you can replace `onMessage` with a function that will get called instead, and from that function, you can test and see if it got called with the correct arguments, etc.

Sinon provides [stubs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.2.0/stubs/) which can be used for this:

```
it("should send information to server", done => {
  const stub = sinon.stub(server.getDispatcher(), 'onMessage').callsFake(data => {
    stub.restore();
    expect(data).to.equal('I am server and I got Hello World\r\n');
    done();
  });
  dummyMachine.socket.write("Hello World\r\n");
});
```

Instead of the original `onMessage`, it will call the "fake function" that you provide. There, the stub is restored (which means that `onMessage` is restored to its original), and you can check and see if it got called with the correct argument.

Because the test is asynchronous, it's using `done`.

There are a few things to consider:

- You can't easily detect if, because of a programming error, `onMessage` doesn't get called *at all*. When that happens, after a few seconds, Mocha will timeout your test, causing it to fail.
- If that happens, the stub won't be restored to its original and any subsequent tests that try to stub `onMessage` will fail because the method is already stubbed (usually, you work around this by creating the stub in an `onBeforeEach` and restore it in an `onAfterEach`)
- This solution won't test the inner workings of `onMessage`, because it's being replaced. It only tests if it gets called, and with the correct argument (however, it's better, and easier, to test `onMessage` separately, by directly calling it with various arguments from your test cases).

Comment: Amazing input! I used a variation of you answer. This is just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the problem is caused by using `Object.freeze` on the object that you would like to spy on.

Most of the time these "spy on" techniques work by overwriting the spied upon function with another function that implements the "spying" functionality (eg: keeps track of the function calls).

But if you're freezing the object, then the function cannot be overwritten.

Comment: Removing the freeze doesn't fix anything (tested). Furthermore if that were the problem, I would actually have a runtime error before the test running and that is not the case!